# How to run the dropwizard server from a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, session, dao, dropwizard

I am using DropWizard with actors. I need to run a test that creates a DAO and returns an object from database. Without running the application, the DAO is always null. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: maybe you can look at https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/testing.html#integrated-testing

Comment: not sure I get the context? Are you trying to test the DAO? Then only create the DAO environment and test it, not dropwizard environment. Or if you need to manipulate DAO to test other units, then mocking is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spock](http://docs.spockframework.org) Framework is my favorite unit testing framework for mocking objects and classes. [Mockito](http://mockito.org) also provides the ability to mock Java or Groovy classes but with a different approach. The documentation is pretty thorough for each.